# Making jQuery mobile compatible with apple-itunes-app

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta

I'm trying to add a `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="">` banner to a jQuery mobile website. The banner works but it is added above jQuery mobile's header div (`<div data-role="header">`), which is problematic in that jQuery scrolls down and hides everything above this div on every page it loads. Which means the user almost never sees the banner. I've been trying to disable all jQuery `document` events and none of these disabled this "feature". I've also tried replacing all `scrollTo(x,y)` by `scrollTo(0,0)` in jquery.js because I've seen that solution somewhere else on the web, and it didn't work either. What else should I do?

Here's what it looks like when the page is loaded:

[image: Problem]

And here's what it should look like when the page is loaded, or how it looks like when the user scrolls all the way up:

[image: Result]

Comment: Could you provide screenshots? Is the iTunes banner visible when you scroll the page all the way up?

Comment: Yes it is. Please see my updated post for the screenshots.

Comment: First of all, don't just blindly replace all occurrences of some code in jQuery's source code like that. That's just senseless.

Comment: Is it a fixed `data-position="fixed"` header?

Comment: Well, it made sense to me that if jQuery functions didn't let me choose the initial scrolling then a function in the js file would. But that wasn't the case. And it is not a `data-position="fixed"` header, this is sadly jQuery Mobile's default behavior.

Comment: I've tried a few other frameworks yesterday and they all seem to have the same behavior. I can't believe none of them is able to handle App Store banners easily. Anyway, I'm going to post an issue on JQM's GitHub and see what happens.

Comment: Did you get any fixes for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with jQuery 1.4 this can now be fixed with the following code:

```
$(document).on( "mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.hideUrlBar = false;
});
```

Source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6081